# How can i use toString method in a optimum way with StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, object, tostring

How could I change this method to become more 
optimal by using 
StringBuilder 
and avoiding string concatenation with + every single time.

Or there may be even better methods

```
public class Cont {
    double valoareImprumut;
    double rata;
    int zileActive;
    TipCont tipCont; //ENUM

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cont [valoareImprumut=" + valoareImprumut + ", rata=" + rata + ", zileActive=" +zileActive + ", tipCont=" + tipCont + "]";
    }
```

Comment: If using Java 8 the compiler will convert that code to use `StringBuilder` anyway. If using Java 9+ it will convert the code to use [`StringConcatFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.html). In other words, you can continue to use `+`.

Comment: Ok, got it. By curiosity, just wanted to compare toString with + concatenation vs StringBuilder without +. But i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lombok and avoid writing **toString()** methods completely :)

https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString